# sed portability: extended regex vs. backslash

Tags: sed, regular-expression, posix, portability

We can write the next command in two ways:

```bsh
# using extended regex
$ echo foobar | sed -E 's/(foo)(bar)/\2\1/'
barfoo
```

And:

```bsh
# using backslashes
$ echo foobar | sed 's/\(foo\)\(bar\)/\2\1/'
barfoo
```

---

Using backslashes means that the command is more portable than the extended regex?

Comment: Note that just by prefixing with a backslash doesn't make it portable. E.g., `+` is ERE but `\+` isn't Posixly. These are GNU sed only constructs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Yes

The [current POSIX standard of `sed`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_02) does not specify the `-E` flag, which enables extended regex (ERE). This alone is enough to conclude that the basic regex (BRE) form `'s/\(foo\)\(bar\)/\2\1/'` is the most portable.

However, even if `-E` were included `sed`'s standard—[and it will be](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=528)—, the [Regular Expressions document](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html) **does not define back-references in EREs**, so the `BRE \(...\) == ERE (...)` association is itself a GNU extension and not guaranteed to be supported by all programs. [POSIX Grep](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html), for example, includes the `-E` flag, but while each one of

```
grep 'ee*'
grep -E 'e+'
grep '\(.\)\1'
```

is compliant,

```
grep -E '(.)\1'
```

is not.

Likewise, there are [reports](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/597857/explain-sed-expression-that-deletes-lines-with-repeated-fields/597860#comment1116153_597859) that concretely illustrate that BSD does not follow the extension:

> [In FreeBSD] `sed -E '/(.)\1/d'` removes lines that have a `1` after some other character.

whereas GNU `sed` would treat that as an back-reference and remove lines containing two equal and adjacent characters.

Comment: See also discussion at https://www.mail-archive.com/austin-group-l@opengroup.org/msg00929.html

Answer (score 2):

`sed -E` means that it will use extended regex (`ERE`), without that flag it uses basic regex (`BRE`).

Not all `sed` versions can deal with extended regex, so yes it is more portable, but not because you use a backslash. That is just normal `BRE`.

See [BRE vs ERE](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/BRE-vs-ERE.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did just self answered second  before yours with the same link :)

Answer (score 1):

The GNU manual [gives the answer](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/BRE-vs-ERE.html):

> **5.2 Basic (BRE) and extended (ERE) regular expression**
>
> Basic and extended regular expressions are two variations on the
> syntax of the specified pattern. Basic Regular Expression (BRE) syntax
> is the default in sed (and similarly in grep). Use the POSIX-specified
> -E option (-r, --regexp-extended) to enable Extended Regular Expression (ERE) syntax.
>
> In GNU sed, the only difference between basic and extended regular
> expressions is in the behavior of a few special characters: ‘?’, ‘+’,
> parentheses, braces (‘{}’), and ‘|’.
>
> With basic (BRE) syntax, **these characters do not have special meaning
> unless prefixed with a backslash (‘\’); While with extended (ERE)
> syntax it is reversed: these characters are special unless they are
> prefixed with backslash (‘\’)**.

Comment: The bold part of the quote is a GNU extension, the manual does not seem to mention it, though. Also the statement about `-E` is not totally accurate. The current issue of the POSIX standard still does not include the `-E` option, although it has been accepted for the next one. An analogous situation is [Is awk's nextfile specified in POSIX?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/588906)